# Is my config enough secure?

Tags: security

I would like to run some applications supplied by my clients on my vm but I want to limit their access.

I wanted to know if I create them a user that can only read/write/execute files on their $home directory and then execute their application with this command `sudo -H -u <client_user> bash -c "command to run their app"` would be secure.

EDIT: The applications supplied by my clients would be executed from a NodeJs server on the vm. So, I don't want them to read/write/execute files from the other applications that have been started from the same NodeJs server.

Comment: Secure against what? What could they or the app do that would be harmful? And why not directly start the app; why wrap it in bash?

Comment: I don't want them to corrupt/stop/delete my vm and/or the other applications that are running on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications which are not allowed to interfere with each other should never run as the `root` user and they should either run as different users or in a chroot jail.

Using different users also requires proper files permittions for the subtree with the data. I.e. the home directories should have `700` permissions.

Comment: So, running an application with `sudo -H -u <client_user> bash -c "command to run their app"` is not good? What should I use?

Comment: @SML You misunderstood me. This command is not wrong but not enough. You have to make sure that the home directory permissions are correct, too.